# Does fundamental theorem of calculus apply to closed curves? If yes why the closed line integral of a function is not zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics, curl

Why closed curve integral $$\oint A.dl$$  doesn't give us zero in many physics related examples?

Closed line/loop/curve/contour have same starting and end points and according to fundamental theorem of calculus we have $$\int_{a}^{b}g'=g(b)-g(a)$$

Doesn't the above relation tell us that integral of a function along closed line must be zero? What I'm missing?

My secondary question is how does this relate to analytic function or contour integral?

Comment: Too bad there are non-conservative force fields.

Comment: Not every vector field is a gradient.

Comment: It's more accurate to say that the integral will always be zero when the region of integration is a single point. Constant curves are not representative of all closed curves.

Comment: @TedShifrin Does that mean fundamental theorem of calculus doesn't apply to conservative forces? And also to analytic functions in complex analysis?

Comment: @Siddaram It might clarify things for you to write down the “fundamental theorem of line integrals “ explicitly, stating the hypotheses explicitly. The fundamental theorem of line integrals tells you what happens when you integrate the gradient of a scalar field along a directed curve. If the vector field you’re integrating is not the gradient of a scalar field, then the fundamental theorem of line integrals does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

In the first integral, $\oint A \cdot \mathrm d l$, you are integrating over a vector field.  In the second integral, $\int_a^b g' \mathrm d x$, you are integrating over a scalar field.  The fundamental theorem of calculus only applies to scalar fields.  However, there is a special subset of vector fields called "conservative vector fields" which sort of obey the fundamental theorem of calculus.  You can look up more about them here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force

Comment: Sort of? …. …..

Comment: If $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable and $C$ is a smooth directed curve from point $a$ to point $b$, then $\int_C \nabla f \cdot \, dr = f(b) - f(a)$. We don’t need to mention conservative vector fields when stating the fundamental theorem of line integrals.

Comment: So fundamental theorem of calculus doesn't apply in all scenarios, especially for vector fields?